# Does sp_api::Core::execute_block return a Result? If not shall I panic when importing a bad block?

Tags: runtime-api

The rustdocs for [execute_block](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_api/trait.Core.html#method.execute_block) indicate that it returns a `Result<(), ApiError>`. However, when I look at a real-world runtime like [in the node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/d79d8cef20bd45ef3961ad1ef3c9a7d677a5e29c/runtime/src/lib.rs#L357) , there is no return type. So I want to clarify whether there is a return type or not, and why is there this apparent discrepancy between the definition and usage?

More practically, if there is no opportunity to return an error when executing a block that you are currently importing, what is the expected behavior when the node attempts to import an invalid block? It seems that FRAME executive just panics in cases like an [invalid signature](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7ffae37f5c5eca019ca8c5448c97767aace0c9fa/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L487), [failed extrinsic](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7ffae37f5c5eca019ca8c5448c97767aace0c9fa/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L503) or [digest mismatch](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7ffae37f5c5eca019ca8c5448c97767aace0c9fa/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L588).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I want to clarify whether there is a return type or not, and why is there this apparent discrepancy between the definition and usage?

Yeah we need to improve the docs for these generated traits. When you declare a runtime api, the macro will generate a node-side trait and a runtime-side trait. The one you linked is the node-side trait. The main changes that are done to the node-side trait are the addition of the `at` parameter and that each function returns a `Result`. The runtime side will be using the exact declaration that is passed to [`decl_runtime_apis!`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_api/macro.decl_runtime_apis.html) (it docs also contain some information on these differences).

> More practically, if there is no opportunity to return an error when executing a block that you are currently importing, what is the expected behavior when the node attempts to import an invalid block?

Panicking is the right approach here. When it panicks the block is seen thrown away as invalid. There is no real need to have it return some `Result`.